# Adding a custom plugin to tinyMCE

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, jeditable

I am using asp.net, i have added tinyMCE editor to my page.
I want to add a custom plugin to TinyEditor that display a drop down list with some variable.
And on selecting a variable from variable list that can be added to cursor place in text area.

How can i achive this or make a custom plugin of this type to be added in my TinyMCE.
For that drop down list on that plugin i want to use Jeditable, that display a drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a moxiecode [tutorial](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) on how to write an own tinymce plugin.

The only problem i see is that you cannot use your own mechanism to display a drop down list.
I think you might have to stick witch the regular tinymce drop-down mechanism.